# Is it okay to extend from classes that extend RealmObject in Java?

Tags: android, database-design, realm

Let me explain with the help of a example. I have a `Transaction` Class (Realm table) which extends `RealmObject`. I want to create a `DeletedTransaction` Class (Realm table) which will store transactions after they are deleted. Instead of making two seperate Classes (`Transaction` and `DeletedTransaction`) which both extend `RealmObject`, can I just make the `Transaction` Class extend `RealmObject` and then can I make the `DeletedTransaction` Class extend the `Transaction` Class?

I know this is possible from the Java perspective, but I wanted to know from the Realm perspective. What are the pros/cons of such an approach?

Comment: The con is that this is not supported, and you'll need two separate classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inheritance in `RealmObject` is not supported. [Issue#761](https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/761)

Instead of extending `RealmObject`, your classes can implement the `RealmModel` interface, adding the `@RealmClass` annotation:

```
@RealmClass
public class User implements RealmModel {

}
```

Reference-[Docs](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#why-do-model-classes-need-to-extend-realmobject)

Comment: You still won't be able to inherit fields between RealmModels though, can you?

Comment: No that is not currently supported AFAIK. :|

Comment: @EpicPandaForce - [help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55758555/realm-java-nested-query-on-same-arrayobject)