# Realm java nested query on same ArrayObject

Tags: realm, realm-java

Current code:

```
mRealm.where(AdditionalData.class)
                        .contains("checklistParticipants.email", a@a.com, Case.INSENSITIVE)
                        .equalTo("checklistParticipants.type", 0)
                        .findAll();
```

which returns me result of similar to `ANY` record.

I want to check in nested query, only return record if and if both condition fulfilled. likewise in nested query, record email must be **a@a.com** and **type=0**

i tried below approach but ended up in same result.

```
mRealm.where(AdditionalData.class)
                        .contains("checklistParticipants.email",a@a.com, Case.INSENSITIVE)
                        .findAll()
                        .where()
                        .equalTo("checklistParticipants.type", 0)
                        .findAll();
```

[image: I have two records]

Below screenshot shows 2 child items,

1. **email= a@a.com** & type = 1
2. email= x@x.com & **type = 0**

Realm checking for both value in either-or approach.

Also tried:

```
  mRealm.where(AdditionalData.class)
                        .equalTo("checklistParticipants.email",a@a.com, Case.INSENSITIVE)
                        .and()
                        .equalTo("checklistParticipants.type", 0)
                        .findAll()
```

> ```
>    classpath "io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin:5.8.0"
> ```

**UPDATE**

```
class AdditionalData {
  String name; 
  RealmList<ChecklistParticipants> checklistParticipants;
}

class ChecklistParticipants{
  String email;
  String type;
  String field3;
}
```

Comment: That's because you should be querying by the `ChecklistParticipants`, then get the additional data through linking objects.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce- i have updated my question, added model, i have only fields in child object. and i want list of Parent class only.

Answer (score 0):

as @EpicPandaForce said you need to use LinkingObjects

```
 class AdditionalData {
      String name; 

      @LinkingObjects(ChecklistParticipants.rlAdditionalData)

      final RealmResults<ChecklistParticipants> linkedChecklistParticipants = null;

      public RealmResults<RealmDocumentLines> getLinkedChecklistParticipants() {
            return linkedChecklistParticipants ;
        }
    }
```

ChecklistParticipants

```
    class ChecklistParticipants{
      String email;
      String type;
      String field3;
      AdditionalData rlAdditionalData;

    public AdditionalData getAdditionalData() {
        return rlAdditionalData;
    }

    public void setAdditionalData(AdditionalData additionalData) {
        this.rlAdditionalData = additionalData ;
    }
    }
```

Then query

```
RealmResult<ChecklistParticipants> result = mRealm.where(ChecklistParticipants.class)
                                .contains("email", a@a.com, Case.INSENSITIVE)
                                .equalTo("type", 0)
                                .findAll();
```

then loop over the result and use `getAdditionalData()` from each item

Comment: it should be inverse relationship. https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#inverse-relationships